# Nested foreach for self referencing table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, public

i am struggling to find a different approach for this code.
I want to create a dropdown list to select a category.
As you can see it is not clean and does not work for multiple levels.
I am not an expert in .NET and would like to learn how a professional does this.

```
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (Category item in db.CategorySet.Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null))
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name });

            foreach (Category subitem in item.SubCategories)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = subitem.Id.ToString(), Text = " - " + subitem.Name });

                foreach (Category subsubitem in subitem.SubCategories)
                {
                    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = subsubitem.Id.ToString(), Text = " - - " + subsubitem.Name });

                    foreach (Category subsubsubitem in subsubitem.SubCategories)
                    {
                        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = subsubsubitem.Id.ToString(), Text = " - - - " + subsubsubitem.Name });
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        this.SubCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Google for "recursive function"

Comment: Please follow these guidelines when asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It makes it much easier to help.

In order for anyone to get an idea of your code, you should provide the class definition of your Category, along with your expected input and output

Comment: @J.N. I'd say it's pretty clear what OP is looking for given the code provided, which is a recursive function.

Comment: @Steve - A recursive function might get OP in trouble here, if the Categories can contain cycles. If the structure is guaranteed to be hierarchal, then a recursive function would be appropriate - but it's certainly not clear from the provided code.

Comment: I updated the question with Entity Framework Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are making hierarchial tree (using the `"-"`, `"- -"`, and so on).

Assuming your `Categories` is non-cyclic, you should consider using recursive function to solve your issue, passing your `list` as well as your printed prefix (the "-") or your "depth" on the recursive search.

Something like below would probably serve:

```
public void addCatToList(List<SelectedItemList> list, int depth, IEnumerable<Category> cats){
    foreach (Category item in cats)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item .Id.ToString(), Text = printDash(depth) + item.Name });
        addCatToList(list, depth + 1, item.SubCategories);
    }

}

private string printDash(int number){
    string dash = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i){
        if (i == 0)
            dash += " ";
        dash += "- ";
    }
    return dash;
}
```

And then you call it the first time with `depth = 0`:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
addCatToList(list, 0, db.CategorySet.Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Give me you bitcoin adress, i'll buy you a beer

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Frank. I do not have bitcoin address though. ;) Also, helping for financial exchange (AFAIK) is forbidden here. You are welcome.